# express.js sharing the session from websocket to http

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, express-session

I can't find a way how to read in the .get() block the specific session value, that was assigned in the .ws() block recently:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const ws = require('express-ws')(app);
const session = require('express-session');
app.use(session({secret: 'secret', resave: true, saveUninitialized: true}));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {

    console.log(req.session.val) //undefined (would like to have "my value")

    res.end("<script>var ws = new WebSocket(window.location.href.replace('http', 'ws')); ws.send(true);</script>");
})
.ws('/', function(ws, req) {

    //trying to assign session
    req.session.val = 'my value';
});

app.listen(80);
```

Please, help.

Comment: pretty sure thats not possible as the ws middleware is after the get middleware.

Comment: Do you realize that the order of real time execution in your code is that the `app.get('/', ...)` request handler gets hit, then you return the webSocket script to the browser and then the browser executes that script and makes a webSocket connection.  So, the `app.get()` handler comes FIRST, before you've set anything in `req.session.val`.

Comment: Thank you. I see that as after the first .get hit, the req.session.val is undefined. But after the second .get hit it could be 'my value' :)

Comment: Would it be possible to connect the ws middleware before the get middleware?